# php global variable scope issue

Tags: php, scope

I have made following program -

```
<?php
global $a;
$a= "me";
echo $a;
function myname() {
echo $a;
}

myname();

?>
```

First echo works but second (inside the function) says undefined variable a

What is wrong?

Comment: This is not program?

Comment: You need to indicate that $a is a global variable ___inside___ your function:
`
    $a= "me";
    echo $a;
    function myname() {
        global $a;
        echo $a;
    }
    
    myname();
`
not specify that it is global ___outside___